# Cache a common resource Using Akka

Tags: concurrency, akka

Hey guys I want to do the following:

Say i have some n actors which are all reading from some common variable called x.
In the background I want to schedule an actor which will keep updating this variable x say every 5-10 minutes.
I dont ever want the n actors to wait for this value to be updated. They should get some value even while x is being updated.
So how can I handle this situation in the best possible way?

Answer (score 1):

Irrespectively of an actor model, two general approaches to solve it are push (when caching agent sends update notifications to clients and they update their local caches) or pull (when client hits caching agent every time).

In either case there is a "current" cache version that should be immutable (to prevent concurrency issues). In the push models clients maintain it locally, on pull models it is maintained in the caching agent. From here, you can have many design choices that are driven by you application needs that lead to different trade-offs.

Roughly, if you want to keep clients simple use pull model. You buy this simplicity at the cost of loosing control of freshness of your cache and giving up the knowledge of update notifications. This also leads to a more complicated communication process.

If you want to be current with the actual data and know when cache is updated (and potentially control update process), use push model. I'd go with that in your case, because it's very simple to implement with actors. A possible implementation in pseudo-scala:

```
class Worker extends Actor {
  var cache: String
  def receive = {
    case CacheUpdate(newValue) => cache = newValue
  } 
}

class Publisher extends Actor {
  val workers = new mutable.ListBuffer[ActorRef]()
  def receive = {
    case AddWorker(actor) => 
      workers += actor
      context.watch(actor) // this is important to keep workers list current
    case Terminated(actor) => workers -= actor
    case Update(newValue) => workers.foreach(_ ! CacheUpdate(newValue))
  }
}
```

You can either send the `AddWorker` message as a part of lifecycle (in which case you need to pass `Publisher` in a constructor), or you can coordinate it externally.

Answer (score 0):

It's considered a bad practice to share mutable objects among different actors, and the way you explain it, your variable 'x' is mutable and it's shared.

The proper way to share information among actors is via immutable messages.

One of the possible solutions would be:

- having an actor that creates your 'n' actors
- this same actor schedules a message to self

  - on the processing of this message, the variable is updated
  - after this, this actor sends a message to its children (the 'n' actors) with a copy (never share something mutable) of the value of variable 'x'
- each of your 'n' actors will receive the new value as a message and they can you whatever is expected from them.

Comment: Or the actors that need the variable can request it when they need. You only need to be aware that the writes and reads will be processed sequentially - which means that the actors may "wait" for the variable to be updated.

Comment: As I said, it is only one of the possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn this [article](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html)  it contains detailed example with caсhing via `ConsistentHashable`